# R datatable styleColorBar based on different column

Tags: r, datatables

I would like to have a styleColorBar in my datatable where the size of the bar is based on a different column.

```
iris %>% 
  select(Species, Petal.Length) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(avg_petal = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
    formatStyle(
        'Petal.Length',
        background = styleColorBar(iris$Petal.Length, 'steelblue'),
        backgroundSize = '100% 90%',
        backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition = 'center'
    )
```

How can I add a color bar to the `Species` column based on the `avg_petal` column?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `valueColumns` argument so that `datatable` knows that a numeric column is used for formating, and then pass the formatting `data$avg_petal` to `styleColorBar`.

```
library(DT)

data <- iris %>% 
  select(Species, Petal.Length) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(avg_petal = mean(Petal.Length))

data %>%  datatable() %>% 
  formatStyle(
    'Species', valueColumns = "avg_petal",
    background = styleColorBar(data$avg_petal, 'steelblue'),
    backgroundSize = '100% 90%',
    backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition = 'center'
  )
```

[image]